# c# Newtonsoft Deserialize Json into object depending on properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Im in a situation where I am receiving Json that can be in two different formats and I am trying to find a good way to deserialize it into their respective objects. I have one Json string that would look like:

```
{
"Id": 1,
"Result": "true",
"Comment": "test comment"
}
```

And the other like:

```
{
"UserId": 12,
"PhoneNumber": "123456789",
"Message": "test message"
}
```

I had created an object that could hold both structures, something like:

```
public class EnvelopeObject
{
   public Structure1 { get; set; }
   public Structure2 { get; set; }
}
```

and ideally after deserializing the json into EvelopeObject I would have one object populated with the data from the json and the other would just be null. I know that this situation would require a custom converter, but after reading the documentation and looking for other examples, Im unsure how to go about this. Is there a simple custom converter solution, or an easier way to go about this?

Comment: If you are using Newtonsoft.Json library then consider TypeNameHandling https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i create you example as another approach. call function which will return tuple of 2 classes, that which will match - would be populated. i use ID (first property) to identify which class to bind
if you set jason as j2 or j1 you will get different class

```cs
void Main()
{
    var j1 = "{\"Id\":1,\"Result\":\"true\",\"Comment\":\"test comment\"}";
    var j2 = "{\"UserId\":12,\"PhoneNumber\":\"123456789\",\"Message\":\"test message\"}";
    
    string json = j2;
    
    GetClassSet(json).Dump();

    
    
}

public (Json1Object, Json2Object) GetClassSet(string json){

    using var doc = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(json);
    object result = null;
    JObject res = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    if (res.First.ToObject<JProperty>().Name.ToUpper() == "ID")
    {
        return(res.ToObject<Json1Object>(), null);
    }
    else
    {
        return (null, res.ToObject<Json2Object>());
    }
}

public class Json1Object
{
    public string Id;
    public string Result;
    public string Comment;
}

public class Json2Object
{
    public string UserId;
    public string PhoneNumber;
    public string Message;
}
```

the results would be [image]
or
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, its the same idea as what I ended up doing to solve the problem. If you hadn't posted this, I would have shared my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and just deserialize both inner objects separately and set them to the Envelope Object. I believe that's simple enough, no need for fancy custom conversion and deserialization.

Here is the code snippet of the `EnvelopeObject` class and two sub classes:

```
public class Json1Object
{
    public string Id;
    public string Result;
    public string Comment;
}

public class Json2Object
{
    public string UserId;
    public string PhoneNumber;
    public string Message;
}

public class EnvelopeObject
{
    public Json1Object? Obj1 { get; set; }
    public Json2Object? Obj2 { get; set; }

    public bool IsJson1Object() => Obj1 is not null;
}
```

With the `IsJson1Object()` method you can check which one is set.

And portion of the code where the `EnvelopeObject` class is being created (with added example strings):

```
String json1 =
    """
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Result": "true",
        "Comment": "test comment"
    }
    """;

String json2 =
    """
    {
        "UserId": 12,
        "PhoneNumber": "123456789",
        "Message": "test message"
    }
    """;

var json1Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json1Object>(json1);
var json2Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json2Object>(json2);
var envelopeObj = new EnvelopeObject
{
    Obj1 = json1Object,
    Obj2 = json2Object
};
```